# 7 query with inner join into 1 query, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a question, how do i make totally 7 query into 1 query? to make the db query lesser? i have 1 table contain all of it, but the `suggest` is a "separator", each suggest i have to load 33 rows and order by dateline, i have think about use any inner join ... etc, but i think that is not a way? correct me if i'm wrong. Would Appreciate for help!THanks!!

This is the mysql query 1

```
$query = DB::query("SELECT t.*, d.did AS dingid, d.id AS dingpid, f.id AS bookmark, f.uid AS buid 
        FROM ".DB::table('comeing_tao')." AS t 
        LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_ding')." AS d ON t.id = d.id AND d.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
        LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_fans')." AS f ON t.id = f.id AND f.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
        WHERE t.suggest = 0 AND t.state = 1 ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 33");
```

This is the mysql query 2

```
$query = DB::query("SELECT t.*, d.did AS dingid, d.id AS dingpid, f.id AS bookmark, f.uid AS buid 
            FROM ".DB::table('comeing_tao')." AS t 
            LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_ding')." AS d ON t.id = d.id AND d.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
            LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_fans')." AS f ON t.id = f.id AND f.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
            WHERE t.suggest = 1 AND t.state = 1 ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 33");
```

This is the mysql query 3

```
$query = DB::query("SELECT t.*, d.did AS dingid, d.id AS dingpid, f.id AS bookmark, f.uid AS buid 
        FROM ".DB::table('comeing_tao')." AS t 
        LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_ding')." AS d ON t.id = d.id AND d.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
        LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_fans')." AS f ON t.id = f.id AND f.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
        WHERE t.suggest = 2 AND t.state = 1 ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 33");
```

This is the mysql query 3

```
$query = DB::query("SELECT t.*, d.did AS dingid, d.id AS dingpid, f.id AS bookmark, f.uid AS buid 
        FROM ".DB::table('comeing_tao')." AS t 
        LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_ding')." AS d ON t.id = d.id AND d.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
        LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_fans')." AS f ON t.id = f.id AND f.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
        WHERE t.suggest = 3 AND t.state = 1 ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 33");
```

This is the mysql query 4

```
$query = DB::query("SELECT t.*, d.did AS dingid, d.id AS dingpid, f.id AS bookmark, f.uid AS buid 
        FROM ".DB::table('comeing_tao')." AS t 
        LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_ding')." AS d ON t.id = d.id AND d.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
        LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_fans')." AS f ON t.id = f.id AND f.uid = ".$_G['uid']." 
        WHERE t.suggest = 4 AND t.state = 1 ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 33");
```

and so on... i skip the following 3 query cos is totally same except the t.suggest = 5, t.suggest = 6, t.suggest = 7

the goal is all the query in one, then play around with the array.

Comment: You could use Union All but I don't know if that is the most efficient way

Comment: `WHERE t.suggest IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`

Comment: Use UNION operator:(query1)UNION(query2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `OR`

```
(t.suggest=3 OR t.suggest=4 OR ...) AND ...
```

if you want max 33 records from each suggest, try [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
(SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...) ...
```

Comment: UNION ? each suggest i must fetch exactly 33 rows, i try google around about union

Comment: just click the link in the `UNION` to see the mysql reference with the example: you can add `LIMIT` to each select in the query

Comment: the query will give you (0-33) rows **of each suggest** (if you have less than 33 rows of some suggest in your DB)

Answer (score 0):

TRY in clause

```
SELECT 
    t.*, d.did AS dingid, d.id AS dingpid, f.id AS bookmark, f.uid AS buid 
FROM 
    ".DB::table('comeing_tao')." AS t 
LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_ding')." AS d ON t.id = d.id AND d.uid = 
     ".$_G['uid']." 
LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('comeing_tao_fans')." AS f ON t.id = f.id AND f.uid = 
     ".$_G['uid']." 
WHERE 
      t.suggest IN(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
AND 
      t.state = 1 
ORDER BY 
      dateline DESC
```

but Limit will not give 33 records for each but 33 for whole return

Comment: too bad, each suggest must fetch === 33 rows, anyway thanks for pointing